# what does traefik config "ingress.kubernetes.io/pass-tls-cert" mean

Tags: traefik

The doc says: "[ingress.kubernetes.io/pass-tls-cert] forward TLS 'Client' certificates to the backend", what does 'Client' mean?  traefik or the end-user?
i set ingress.kubernetes.io/pass-tls-cert whit true , and i want pass the end-user Client certificates to my service, but failed

Comment: provide more information on what exactly you're having an issue with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

@Saveen thanks for your response
I have got a reply from traefik group, they said:
"Unfortunately, this option does not work as expected.
In fact, it activates the TLS between Træfik and the backend with the first certificate defined in the Træfik configuration but it does not pass the client certificate to the backend.
We already analyzed this issue and we'll propose a fix ASAP."